# PHP singletons and use of extended static properties

Tags: php, class, properties, static, singleton

I've been running in circle for a couple hours with this problem.
Maybe it's not possible at all, or maybe there's a better OOP solution for this...

For example: I have two classes

```
class Base
{
    public static $config;
}

class System extends Base
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$config = 2;
    }
}

class Core extends Base
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$config = 3;
    }
}
```

I always access those classes as singletons: System::HelloWorld(), Core::DoStuff();

I want the $Config attribute to be inherited from the Base class because I'm gonna need it in
almost every single class, so why define it every time over and over again.

The problem is, $Config attribute overrides itself as sonn as another class sets it's own value to it:

```
System::$config = 2;
Core::$config = 3;
print System::$config // it's 3 instead of 2
```

I do understand why that happens: Because the Base::$Config is Static - and that way - shared trough all the children. I do not want this, I want it to be static in each child, but not trough of it's children. It would be no problem, if I would actually instantiate the System and the Core classes, but I need them as Singletons...

Help me out here, maybe you know a better design pattern then this.

Comment: You know that singletons and statics are really hard to impossible to cover with unit tests. Using such an approach is often considered bad practice. I'm not saying it must be but think and read about it, if you're interested in improving your overall approach.

Comment: I'm not a fan of them either. but i want to offer a simple access to all the different modules, without the need to instantiate them, keep track of instances, inject the same instance in to all classes that will need it etc.

long way:
$a = new a(); $a->Foo();
echo $a->x;

desired way:
a::Foo();
echo a::$x;

Comment: If this is something serious, it will come back to haunt you, I promise. But just go your way and find it out for yourself, probably everybody has to do that :).

Comment: if you use: a::$x, $x has to be a static property, because the class is used as a static one.

now imagine, class b has a property $x too, but with another value (b::$x). so why define $x in each class as a static property over and over again, if you can build a parent class, that has the $x property, and all the others inherit from it. but now: classes are used as static, so the parent has to be static too, buuut if it's static, then all the classes that will have it as parent, gonna share the $x.

Comment: @markus Here I am, four years later, laughing over my *design decisions*. I should have read some basic books about software design back then. *Me* from 2017 totally agrees with *you (marcus)* from 2013 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use static variable at all,

```
<?php
Class Base{
 public $Config;
}

Class System Extends Base{
 Public static $obj = null;
 Public static Function HelloWorld() {
  if (!System::$obj) System::$obj = new System();

  // call the object functions
  // $obj->HelloWorld();
 }

 Public Function __Construct()
 {
     $this->Config = 2;
 } 
}

Class Core Extends Base{
 Public Function __Construct()
 {
     $this->Config = 3;
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: But I'm never gonna instatiate the System and Core classes...
If I call System::$parent::$Config = 999; and then print System::$parent::$Config - it wont be 999 because it's not static and that value get's lost?

Comment: The singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. So you should instantiate an object in your static function such as System::HelloWorld().

Comment: I see.. How do you call it then, if you use you class directly, without instantiation.

Not: $instance = new System(); $instance->HelloWorld();
But: System::HelloWorld()

Comment: I have updated System class in the answer. The class has static variable $obj that holds the only object. The static function HelloWorld instantes the singletons only when necessary.

Comment: that's not really a clean solution in my opinion, getting the instance all the time etc.. that would mean, each method has to instantiate the class over and over again... I'll have to use another approach, or create completely static class.

Comment: the class object is not being instantiated over and over again in singleton pattern and also in the above example. It only instantiate when required. Other pattern such as abstract factory pattern may fit you but one of your requirement is singletons.

Comment: This line: if (!System::$obj) System::$obj = new System();
You'll have to call it over and over again? in each method?
You could bypass this by using a custom construct and autoloading:
function init(){ if (!System::$obj) System::$obj = new System(); }

but then again: if you want to work with the "actual" instance - you'll have to use self::$obj->HelloWorld() instead of self::HelloWorld()

it's kinda strange to explain...

Comment: All i want is using static classes, whitout the need to intantiate them. that's easy. but if i want them to inherit something from a sort of a "base" class, that's where i get in trouble. because in a static class, the parent HAS to be static too, but then that "base" class gonna be the same trough ALL of the classes that inherit from it.

i'll check your tip with the factory pattern. thank you for you patience!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a relatively good solution for this. For those who may face the same problem, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197338/php-my-way-of-threating-static-classes)

Comment: Please don't use this solution :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
// static change the attributes of the scope
class base
{
    public static $config;

}

class a extends base
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$config = 1;
    }
}
class b extends base
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$config = 2;
    }
}

a::$config = 2;
b::$config = 3;
echo a::config, ',', b::$config; // 3,3
$a = new a();
echo base::$config, a::$config, b::$config, $a::$config; // 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: That's a good explanation of my problem =) you have a solution?

Comment: How does this address the problem?